# OrderByDesc col1 divided by col2

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I need to `sort` a result based on `col1` divided by `col2`.. so what I would like to do is something like this:

```
var x = uploadsQuerySelectionBuilder.Where(e => e.uploadNumberOfVotes 
> 0)**.OrderByDescending(e=>(e.uploadScore/e.uploadNumberOfVotes))
** : uploadsQuerySelectionBuilder;
```

As for now.. it doesnt seems to order the result at all, but its just random..
Is this even possible, how would I get this to work ?

EDIT:

```
var x = tSearch.SortByDate != false ? uploadsQuerySelectionBuilder.Where(e => e.uploadNumberOfVotes > 0).OrderByDescending(e => (e.uploadScore / e.uploadNumberOfVotes)) : uploadsQuerySelectionBuilder;
```

is the very valid and "compileable" code :).. the other one were not written in VS, so my bad..

Comment: You code looks "just random". Can you post a verbatim copy of your code please, because what you've posted here wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
var x = uploadsQuerySelectionBuilder
           .Where(e => e.uploadNumberOfVotes > 0)
           .Select(e => new { Val = e, ScoreishThing = e.uploadScore/e.uploadNumberOfVotes })
           .OrderByDescending(e=> e.ScoreishThing)
           .Select(e=>e.Val);
```

Comment: Thanks!
I will try this soon :), seems to be what im looking for :)

Comment: That almost did the trick.. but the thing is that I want to keep all the entities that has a score that equal to zero aswell.. this seems to remove them..
So:
Sort all entities that has a score > 0 but dont remove the entities that has zero.. Im not really sure about how to explain it, but I hope you get it :)

Comment: Does `select`ing a new anonymous object _really_ make a difference here?